# Targeting one Word on the whole Website - SMALL CAPS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a company Name that has a specific writing. The word-part "ulum" should be written in Small Caps - all over the whole website. But I don't know where to put it - and I don't know why it's not working.

I need to target every of these across the whole website.

Please help. :)

At first I tried this:

```
C<span style="font-variant: small-caps">ulum</span>NATURA <sup>®</sup>
```

But it only works if I put it in every Word across the Site.. that's toooooooo much :)

```
<p style="font-family: serif; font-variant: small-caps;">CulumNATURA<sup style="font-size: .6em; line-height: 2em;">&reg;</sup></p>
```

Sincerely,
Rina

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving your style into a stylesheet, then changing the HTML to be more concise and easier to update in the future with classes:

```
C<span class="small-caps">ulum</span><span class="caps">NATURA</span> <sup><span class="sup">®</span></sup>
```

Comment: Hi that looks awesome! The problem for me is - I work with elementor Pro on Wordpress. Can you tell me where to put this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Elementor Pro but I did find that they have a community area on Facebook at https://www.facebook.com/groups/Elementors/

At first glance there appears to be a way to add custom CSS 
for example, Edit Button > Advanced > Custom CSS. So you might want to look for another Custom CSS for the content instead of a button to solve your needs.